# Angular sample followup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Here is the code snippet from Angular tutorial, instead of calling the ng-app directive in the html tag, am creating a span tag and calling it there. Why is the UL list in the javascript not showing up?? Thanks for your help!!

```js
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phoneCatApp', []);
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListController', function PhoneListController($scope) {
    $scope.phones = [{
        name: 'Nexus S',
        snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
    }, {
        name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
        snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
    }, {
        name: 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
        snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
    }
    ];
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My HTML File</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<span ng-app="phoneCatApp">
<body ng-controller="PhoneListController">
<p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>

<p>1 + 2 = {{1 + 2}}</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        <span>
            {{phone.name}}</span>

        <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>

    </li>
</ul>

</body>
    </span>
</html>
```

Comment: wrap `span` and `p` inside `div` and use `ng-repeat` in div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `HTML` doesn't like `<span>` outside `<body>`

```js
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phoneCatApp', []);
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListController', function PhoneListController($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [{
    name: 'Nexus S',
    snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
  }, {
    name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
    snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
  }, {
    name: 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
    snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
  }];
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="phoneCatApp" ng-controller="PhoneListController">
  <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>

  <p>1 + 2 = {{1 + 2}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
      <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes,m ur correct, when I set the span inside the body, it works. How come other angular directives work and not ng-repeat when span is outside of body tag., thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure but you shouldn't put span outside body anyway.